# System.data.Sqlite: Return number of affected rows no matter if Query or NonQuery is used

Tags: sqlite, powershell, ado.net, system.data.sqlite

I'm using `System.Data.SQLite` ADO.NET provider for SQLite and the following Powershell code to execute queries (and nonqueries) against a Sqlite3 DB:

```
Function Invoke-SQLite ($DBFile,$Query) {

    try {
        Add-Type -Path ".\System.Data.SQLite.dll"
    }
    catch {
        write-warning "Unable to load System.Data.SQLite.dll"
        return
    }
    if (!$DBFile) {
        throw "DB Not Found" R
        Sleep 5
        Exit
    }
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection
    $conn.ConnectionString="Data Source={0}" -f $DBFile
    $conn.Open()
    $cmd = $Conn.CreateCommand()
    $cmd.CommandText = $Query
    #$cmd.CommandTimeout = 10
    $ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
    $da = New-Object System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter($cmd)
    [void]$da.fill($ds)
    $cmd.Dispose()
    $conn.Close()

    write-host ("{0} Row(s) returned " -f ($ds.Tables[0].Rows|Measure-Object|Select -ExpandProperty Count)) 

    return $ds.Tables[0]
}
```

The problem is: while it is trivial to know how many rows have been SELECTed in a query operation, the same is not true if the operation is an INSERT,DELETE or UPDATE (nonqueries)

I know I could use the ExecuteNonQuery method, but i need a generic wrapper which returns number of affected rows while being agnostic about the query it executed (as Invoke-SQLCmd would do, for example)

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: should I put up a bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments before the answer:

- System.data.Sqlite supports executing multiple SQL statements for one command, as long as the CommandText has each valid statements delimited by a semicolon (;).  This means that there could be a mixture of queries and DML statements (i.e. INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).  The fact that you do not want to distinguish between the type of statement in `$Query` tells me that you are likely just passing statements blindly, so it could contain any combination of statements.  Simply getting only one value (whether from a query or DML) seems too limiting.
- Using a DataAdapter to fill a dataset just to get counts is inefficient.  Instead, it may be better to just get a DataReader object and count the returned rows.  This also allows a separate count for each query statement to be retrieved, something that gets obscured by using the DataAdapter object.  (Perhaps enumerating all tables in the resultant dataset could get the same number, but I'm not certain that would always be equivalent.)

  - One good thing is that if you insist on using a DataAdapter, it will still execute DML statements (even though the expected result is query that returns rows).  The dataset will not be changed (filled), but all statements in the command text will still affect changes in the database, so the following solution will still be useful.
- Even if the code had works, I assume that the line which prints "{0} Rows returned" is meant to get a simple count, but `$ds.Tables[0].Rows` needs to be `$ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count`.

---

Notes about this particular solution:

- The key is to call either of the sqlite [SQL functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#changes) `changes()` or `total_changes()`.  These can be retrieved using SQL:  `SELECT total_changes();`.  I recommend getting `total_changes()` before and after a command, then subtracting the difference.  That will get changes for multiple statements executed by one command.
- I'm not a PowerShell guru, so I tested everything in C#.  Treat the code below more as pseudo code since it may need tweaking.

The code:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection
try {
  $conn.ConnectionString="Data Source={0}" -f $DBFile
  $conn.Open()

  $cmdCount = $Conn.CreateCommand()
  $cmd = $Conn.CreateCommand()
  try {
    $cmdCount.CommandText = "SELECT total_changes();"

    $beforeChanges = $cmdcount.ExecuteScalar()

    $cmd.CommandText = $Query

    $ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $da = New-Object System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter($cmd)

    $rows = 0
    try {
      [void]$da.fill($ds)
      foreach ($tbl in $ds.Tables) {
         $rows += $tbl.Rows.Count;  
      }    
    } catch {}

    $afterChanges = $cmdcount.ExecuteScalar()
    $DMLchanges = $afterChanges - $beforeChanges

    $totalRowAndChanges = $rows + $DMLchanges

    # $ds.Tables[0] may or may not be valid here.
    # If query returned no data, no tables will exist.
  } finally {
    $cmdCount.Dispose()
    $cmd.Dispose()
  }
} finally {
  $conn.Dispose()
}
```

Alternatively, you could eliminate the DataAdapter:

```
    $cmd.CommandText = $Query

    $rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

    $rows = 0
    do {
      while ($rdr.Read()) { 
        $rows++
      }
    } while ($rdr.NextResult())
    $rdr.Close();
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for! I semplified my code to request just one type of query (select/insert/update/delete) per query whenever possible, still your solution handles everything! Great code, thanks!

Comment: For anyone using the code above: it is mostly correct, just a couple of $ missing (but C Perkins warned about it) in places like cmdcount.ExecuteScalar() -> $cmdcount.ExecuteScalar()

Comment: ..and just out of curiosity.. what's the purpose of saving the Total_changes before executing the statement?.. I mean, calling the total_changes() just AFTER the statement isn't enough? (At least, that's what I see in my tests, since before statement execution is always 0)

Comment: @Aldo  The function `total_changes()` is valid for the current connection and so starts at zero when the connection opens.  For this code in particular it is not necessary, but I was coding **a more generalized pattern** that could be used if the same connection were used repeatedly and multiple statements were executed at once.  I always keep in mind that answers on Stack Overflow are not just for the immediate question, but meant as a resource for others.  I'm glad it helped!